# Facing empty character in list input

Tags: python, pycharm

Was trying to make a code that adds 4 inputted numbers

```
r=[]
for item in range(1,5):
    r.append(input())
print(r)
```

But I am facing an issue in PyCharm of getting a null character in between inputs
The output received is as follows

```
6
7
8
['6', '', '7', '']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The same error wasn't replicated on another laptop with PyCharm.
Tried running this code on Jupyter notebook on the same machine but the error wasn't occurring.
for ref my Jupyter output was (which should be the ideal output)

```
1
4
56
6
['1', '4', '56', '6']
```

Comment: This is clearly a PyCharm issue and nothing to do with Python *per se*. You should eliminate IDE issues by running your script(s) directly in your Python environment (command line)

Answer (score 1):

That's PyCharm regression https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54238/STDIN-is-lost-for-a-second-input-call

The fix is coming to 2022.1.2 (Release Candidate this week) and 2022.2.